# UINavigationController: app freezes

Tags: ios, xcode

In myAppDelegate.m:

```
MainViewController *mainViewController         = [ [MainViewController alloc] init];
UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc]
                                         initWithRootViewController:mainViewController];

[navController setNavigationBarHidden:YES];
[[self window] setRootViewController:navController];
```

In MainViewController.m nothing special, just one action tied to a button:

```
- (IBAction)go:(id)sender {
   if (!whereamiViewController)
   {
      whereamiViewController = [[WhereamiViewController alloc] init];
   }
   [[self navigationController] pushViewController:whereamiViewController animated:YES];

}
```

And in WhereamiViewController.m just a button to show another screen in UINavigationViewController:

```
-(IBAction)showList:(id)sender
{

PointsViewController *container = [[PointsViewController alloc] init];
[[self navigationController] pushViewController:container animated:YES];
}
```

And:

```
@interface PointsViewController : UITableViewController

@end
```

Everything fine. But when I land on the last screen, PointsViewController, and I go back on WhereamiView, the app freeze, and Xcode shows a trap at CoureFoundation, CFHas.

Now, I know that Objective-C is not php, but this is a simple example indeed: what am I missing? There is a method to debug the problem?

The debugger says:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-  [__NSCFType _forgetDependentConstraint:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

This morning I ran the app inside the simulator and no crashes!! How is it possible? If I run inside the iPhone crash, in the simulator no crash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[PARTIALLY SOLVED]
This is very strange: After debugging everything and deleting every suspicious declaration, nothing improved. Same crash SIGABRT. After rebooting both iPhone and Mac, everything is fine!

Answer (score 0):

I am not really seeing where the problem is as it occurs outside of the code you have posted. I may be missing something, but if the app crashes when you go back to `whereamiViewController`, how do you actually go back? I am not seeing where it's detailed here.

With `navigationControllers` like this, you would push (to add) or pop (to remove) `viewControllers` to move up and down the  navcontroller tree. As it is at this point that the app seems to be crashing, it may be worth postings how you are dong this? Where are you popping the container (PointsViewController *).

From the code you've posted, I suspect you may be trying to move back to the `whereamiViewController` by re-pushing it again.

Comment: There is nothing special outside the code. But you right that maybe I man not watching something. However, I go back to whereamiViewController just by pushing the back button which appears automatically on top of the UINavigationBar. I added the error message of the debugger in my post.

Comment: That error describes the instance when you try to call a method that doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

Tim is right. Popping the PointsViewController is the way I would do it, too.

What does your Xcode saying? Can you provide the content of the debugger?
That would be more helpful to track down what's going wrong.

Comment: The error message is this: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFType _forgetDependentConstraint:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance